# Php with WordPress how to call up permalinks to two separate posts

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

i'm building a recent posts function into a wordpress site, i've got it to call up two different featured images but they are both linking to the same post, can anyone see where i am going wrong?

```
<?php
        $args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 2,
'order_by' => 'date',
'order' => 'desc'
);

$post = get_posts( $args );
if($post) {
$post_id = $post[0]->ID;
if(has_post_thumbnail($post_id)){
    ?>
    <div class="grid_24">
        <div class="grid_12">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
    <?php
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'medium');
    ?>
    </a>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_12">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
    <?php
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id,'medium');
    ?>
        </a>
        </div>

    </div>
    <?php

    }
}
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `echo get_the_permalink($post->ID)` to get the uri for the posts

So it looks like in your case you'd need

```
echo get_the_permalink($post[0]->ID);
```

and

```
echo get_the_permalink($post[1]->ID);
```

in the href

However you're probably better off creating a foreach loop to go through the posts from the get_posts function

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_permalink/

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first of all, you are not looping the query you have made ( e.g $posts = get_posts( $args ); ) you are just displaying the 1st post's thumbnail and the thumbnail of the current page.

You need to loop the post like this :

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'order_by' => 'date',
    'order' => 'desc'
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );
?>

<?php if ( !empty( $posts ) ) :?>
    <div class="grid_24">
        <?php foreach ( $posts as $post ) : ?>\
            <?php if( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) ?>
                <div class="grid_12">
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $post->ID ) ) ?>">
                        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'size_here'); ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach?>
    </div>
<?php endif;
```

Comment: Sorry,  the double echo was mistyping.

Comment: This doesnt display anything for me

Comment: @dovefromhell can you please give me more information? What did $posts return? What markup is shown do you see some errors?

Comment: It doesnt error but returns this markup

<div class="grid_24">
   <div class="grid_12">
   <a href="http://www.icoza.net/allweathercoating/about-2/">
       </a>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: @dovefromhell  Can you please add this var_dump( get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'medium' ) ); exit; and show me the result ?